# contents of json field to be merged - Laravel application

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.4

I need a unique list of keywords.This is the query

```
$array['keywords'] = DB::table('job_posts')
                ->pluck('keywords')->toArray();
```

In my job_posts table, keywords column is a json entry[laravel cast json]

For record 1, keywords field value is

```
["jquery","html","css","js"]
```

For record 1, keywords field value is

```
["jquery","html","scss"]
```

I need aa array like this

```
array('jquery','html','css','js','scss')
```

so as to give options for a select box()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has some cool array [helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-flatten) that you can use.

So, for example:

```
$test = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
];

$flattened = array_flatten($test);
$unique    = array_unique($flattened);

dd($unique);
```

would output:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => "a"
  1 => "b"
  2 => "c"
  3 => "d"
  7 => "e"
]
```

Comment: Changed DB::table('job_posts')
       ->pluck('keywords')->toArray(); to JobPost::pluck('keywords')->toArray(); [cast to json]. Then applied your method.It's working .Thank you...